# Reference error after repointing application from .NET 4.5 to 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I build an application pointing to .NET 4.5 but need to run it on a server that only has .NET 4.0, so I retargeted the application and uninstalled/reinstalled several references as prompted:

- Antlr
- EntityFramework
- Newtonsoft.Json
- Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
- Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
- WebGrease

I now have no build errors in Visual Studio, but when running the project I get the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Which makes sense because I had to install version 4.0, but how do I remove this error?

It does not appear that I am referencing any .NET 4.5 dependencies in `packages.config`:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="AspNetMvc" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.9.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.3" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="PagedList" version="1.17.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="PagedList.Mvc" version="4.5.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

It looks like the offending reference is in ~/Views/Web.config:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <!-- Namespaces removed -->
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install 4.5 on the server or rebuild all projects and dependencies for 4.0. If you are using a 4.5 dependency, you need to remove it and add a 4.0 counterpart instead.

Comment: I wish I could just install 4.5 but unfortunately that's not an option. I did uninstall MVC 5 and reinstall MVC 4 but it is still referencing 5 somewhere. It does not appear in the list of packages and I have no build errors (the compilation error occurs when running locally as well as on the server). Is there an easy way to see if I am using an 4.5 dependencies? Updating question with packages.config

Comment: Manually changing the referenced version in ~/Views/Web.config allowed the project to run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have installed the incorrect version of the MVC Framework. Check which version you have referenced in your project and ensure you have that version available on the server.